# I've installed windows 10 with bios set to legacy, windows hangs on shut down?

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, lenovo-laptop, windows-installation

I've installed Windows 10 on my new Lenovo G50-70 with Bios set to legacy boot, At first i didn't know how to enter to the bios so i pressed alt+f12 to choose which device to boot from so i found 4 options where there efi+HDD so i used that option to install windows 10 with GPT partitions. after that Windows 10 start to get slow and refuse to shut-down, and now after i figured out how to enter to the bios i changed the boot to UEFI.

My question is what i've done did correct the mistake that i did or i should to reinstall Windows 10?

Comment: Just a guess, but this could be related to the Windows 10 [Hibernation](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) and [Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) features, both of which ***must*** be disabled in order to safely dual-boot with Windows 10. Also and FWIW, you did *not* install in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. This is probably unrelated to your problem, but you should probably disable the BIOS/CSM/legacy support in your firmware.

Comment: What?  Are you saying you installed Windows 10 with legacy mode enable, then after some period of time, installed it again in EFI mode?

Comment: @Ramhound No i didn't, i just changed the Bios to Boot as EFI mode.